# button shadow when clicked is covered by other widget

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Button's shadow is happened when click the button.
But, the shadow is covered by other widget.
How can I resolve this?

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      total += i;
    }
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 343.43,
          height: 150.62,
          decoration: RadiusAndShadow().getDecoration(),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Header(text: name),
              EcRow(t1: '칼로리', t2: '1회당 ${calorie}kcal'),
              EcRow(t1: '카드개수', t2: '$count 개'),
              EcRow(t1: '반복횟수', t2: '$total회'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          width: 343.43,
          height: 150.62,
          top: 17,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return ExEdit();
                  }));
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.edit_outlined,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I used Stack widget.
In Stack, there are Container and Positioned.
In Container, there are Header and Text.
In Positioned, there is an IconButton.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand exactly what happens since you did not provide any code, but I think when you click on the IconButton a splash effect happens and not exactly a shadow so inside the IconButton add:

```
splashRadius: 20,
```

you can also disable this effect:

```
 return Theme(
  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(),
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: const WelcomeScreen(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your IconButton with widget Material

in Material
color: Colors.transparent,

in IconButton
splashRadius: 20,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).